# Secret decoder ring

Tags: word, wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle

I was digging in my dad's trunk and I found some sort of 1940s secret decoder ring.  Not quite sure how it works, but anyway, one of the lines has become almost illegible (#T#######).  Can someone help me to restore it?

```
              ^
              |
              |
   <wrap around to bottom>
  
     |    RELEASED     |
     |  CONTRIVANCE    |
     |   RETRIBUTION   |
     |    BELIEVED     |
     |    EMBATTLED    |
     |    UNMARKED     |
     |   DISPATCHED    |
     |   ENCOURAGE     |
     |   DISSENTER     |
     |    INSEMINATE   |
     |   PROPORTION    |
     |   CONFOUNDED    |
     |    SQUIRMING    |
     |    #T#######    |
     |   PREFECTURE    |
     |  UNDETERRED     |
     |    DELECTABLE   |
     |  CONGREGATION   |
     |   SUCCESSIONAL  |
     |   UNIMPEDED     |
     |   OVERDRESSED   |
     |    FORGOING     |
     |    DECEIVING    |
  
   <wrap around to top>
              |
              |
              v
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Let me take a closer look at your ring... ah, it seems you missed

> the small crack running down the middle, all the way around the ring.

So if you just pull here, and push this way...

> you can separate the two halves, and twist them a bit relative to each other!
>
>  [image: word list, with right halves of words moved up by one]
>
>  Now this makes the new words `SQUI?????` and `?T??CTURE`. The latter has to be STRUCTURE or STRICTURE, and the only way to complete `STR[u/i]?????` and `SQUI?????` the same way is with GGLE[s/d/r].
>
>  So the missing word is **STRUGGLES**! (Or STRUGGLED, or (less likely) STRUGGLER).

Comment: rot13(Gur zvffvat jbeq frrzf gb unir avar yrggref, znlor lbh arrq gb znxr vg cyheny?)

Comment: I chose the plural just to make it more intimidating, but I will accept either singular or plural.  The solving logic is the same.

Comment: @SlowMagic Ah, my bad - I had that at first, but then saw the ambiguity and recounted... and then *mis*counted that time around. Fixed!